# How do I avoid unused setState functions? Can React useState be created without a setter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, use-state

I'm currently reducing / removing npm warnings on a React site.

A large number of these warnings are caused by the setState function as seen below, being 'unused'.

```
const [state, setState] = useState('some state');
```

Which of the following would be a better way to remove these warnings? Or is there a better way to approach the issue?

1.

```
const[state] = useState('some state');
```

2. 

```
const state = 'some state';
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If `setState` isn't being used at all, then it's a value that never changes so can be a constant (2.). You could probably move it out of the component as well.

Comment: you might want to initialize state with some value from props, and then ignore future values of that props, in that case moving the state outside component wouldn't work.

Answer (score 14):

If the setter of state is unused, you can avoid it the `useState`. You can keep the value in a const (in the body of the component), or move outside of the component.

`setState` is used when it's needed to be aware of the changes in the value stored in state. This way the component knows when to re-render.

Comment: Thanks, what is the benefit (if any) of moving the const value outside of the component?

Comment: Whenever the component re-renders it doesn't have to initialise the variable again, whereas outside the component, it needs to initialize once and when the component re-renders it just retrieves the value.

Comment: @ljbc1994 the practical difference is irrelevant.

Comment: @ThomasFox I think it´s just organizational.

Answer (score 12):

You may be struggling with this (it's how I came to this question):

```
const [cookies, setCookies] = useCookies(['cookiename']);
```

Throwing a warning: `'setCookies' is assigned a value but never used [no-unused-vars]`

If you would write `cookies = useCookies...` it would NOT work.

The solution is:

```
const [cookies,] = useCookies(['cookiename']);
```

Comment: Thank you. Came looking for this answer, because of `useSearchParams()`.

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered this need. In addition to other suggestions, `useRef` could be used

For details: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables