# What necessitates using the value returned from useState and completely ignoring the setter function?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I stumbled onto code like this

```
const [activeChoice] = useState("flights");
```

**Question** `Why would anyone just use the value returned from useState`. The person who wrote the code is obviously never planning to update the value since he/she didn't destructure the setter function. Wouldn't it be easier to do just use a variable instead of adding the extra code "noise"? for example

```
const activeChoice = "flights";
```

Comment: This question appears to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65722635/how-do-i-avoid-unused-setstate-functions-can-react-usestate-be-created-without

Comment: fair point @GiorgiMoniava ;)